# Problems in cupy

Tags: python-3.x

```
import numpy as np
import cupy
import json
import time

regs_feats = cupy.random.normal(size=[200000, 512])
regs_id = cupy.random.randint(1, 110000, (200000,))

def calculate_distance(feats, regs_feats, threshold):
    t0 = time.time()
    try:
        src = cupy.asarray(feats)
        distances = cupy.zeros(shape=(src.shape[0], regs_feats.shape[0]))
        for i in range(src.shape[0]):
            distances[i] = cupy.linalg.norm(src[i] - regs_feats, axis=1)
    except:
        print('failed')
        raise
    candidate_num = 2 if regs_feats.shape[0] > 5 else regs_feats.shape[0]
    t1 = time.time()
    work_numbers, min_distances = [], []
    for i in range(distances.shape[0]):
        min_indices = distances[i].argsort()[: candidate_num]
        numb, dis = [], []
        for j in range(candidate_num):
            numb.append(regs_id[min_indices[j].get()])
            #dis.append(distances[i][min_indices[j]])
        work_numbers.append(numb)
        #min_distances.append(dis)
    print('time1: {},time2: {}'.format(t1 - t0, time.time() - t1))
    return work_numbers, min_distances

if __name__ == '__main__':
    feature = cupy.random.normal(size=[1, 512])
    for i in range(5):
        work_numbers, min_distances = calculate_distance(feats=feature, regs_feats=regs_feats, threshold=1)
```

*The result of running the above program

```
time1: 0.04357028007507324, time2: 0.004300832748413086
time1: 0.00022912025451660156, time2: 0.04258894920349121
time1: 0.0002181529998779297, time2: 0.04140281677246094
time1: 0.00023508071899414062, time2: 0.04133772850036621
time1: 0.00021719932556152344, time2: 0.04119539260864258
```

Problem: When in first loop, time2 is only 4.3ms.But in next loops，time2 reachs 41+ms.I use the cupy.get() or cupy.asnumpy() mainly due to getting the indexs when I can use them in cpu.
I want time2 to stays under 5ms. Does anybody know how to solve this?